# How to get mix-blend-mode scroll effect using javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, mix-blend-mode

I'm looking for a way to change the background color of a certain element based on the background. What you can do in css with mix-blend-mode but I want to be able to set the color.

Preferable I can use the same trick with an SVG.

To show what I'm getting at here is a jsfiddle with mix-blend-mode:
https://jsfiddle.net/5p69j4st/7/

```css
.block {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #fff;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}

.is-green {
  display: block;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

.is-white {
  display: block;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
</div>
<div class="is-green">
</div>
<div class="is-white">
</div>
<div class="is-green">
</div>
```

So I want the fixed element with class block to be white when in the green.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a trick where you can put the coloration of the fixed element within the different block considering `background-attachment:fixed`

```css
.block {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  border:1px solid;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.is-green {
  display: block;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background:
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) 10px 10px/25px 25px fixed no-repeat,
    green;
}

.is-white {
  display: block;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background:
    linear-gradient(#000,#000) 10px 10px/25px 25px fixed no-repeat,
    #fff;
}
body {
 padding-bottom:200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
</div>
<div class="is-green">
</div>
<div class="is-white">
</div>
<div class="is-green">
</div>
```

Of course, there 2 main drawbacks with this solutions: In case there is a content it will break the *magic* of the background trick and you are obliged to change the different values in different places.

To overcome this we can consider pseudo element and CSS variables:

```css
:root {
  --t:10px;
  --l:10px;
  --h:25px;
  --w:25px;
}

.block {
  position: fixed;
  z-index:999;
  top: var(--t);
  left: var(--l);
  height: var(--h);
  width: var(--w);
  border:1px solid;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  color:red;
}

.is-green {
  display: block;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
  background:green;
}
.is-green::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:99;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) var(--l) var(--t)/var(--w) var(--h) fixed no-repeat;
}

.is-white {
  display: block;
  position:relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  color:#000;
}
.is-white::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:99;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:
    linear-gradient(#000,#000) var(--l) var(--t)/var(--w) var(--h) fixed no-repeat;
}
body {
 padding-bottom:200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
Hi
</div>
<div class="is-green">
  lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum
</div>
<div class="is-white">
 lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum
</div>
<div class="is-green">
 lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum
</div>
```

Now you only need to change the color of gradient to whataver you want.